# Creating and Solving Equation from Word Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, word-problem

I have this word problem that I cannot figure out how to put into an equation:

> Suppose that we agree to pay you $9$ cents for every math problem you solved correctly, and fine you $5$ cents for every problem done incorrectly. If at the end of $42$ questions, we do not owe each other any money, how many problems did you solve correctly?

I know the solution is $15$, but I did not solve it with an equation. I need help figuring out how to organize this into an equation.

Comment: Start by defining $x$ as some value, like the number of questions solved correctly

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I do not understand what order my values need to go in to make this into a working equation and solve it. I know that ultimately, I will arrive at the answer of 27 wrong questions and 15 correct questions, however, I do not know how to solve this with a created equation.

Comment: What special property in the problem provides us an indicator of what $x$ might be? How can you describe that property mathematically?

Comment: To make an equation, you need to equate two quantities. Which quantities are equal? If $x$ is the number of correctly solved questions, how much money do you get?

Comment: @Vasili 1.35 for 15 correct questions and -1.35  for 27 incorrect questions. How do I write this in an equation though?

Comment: Can you write an expression using $x$ for amount earned for answering correctly? $x$ questions, $9$ cents each, the total is ...

Comment: Yes. .09$x$ = 1.35

Comment: That's right. You get $0.09x$ but this is also equal to the amount subtracted for answering incorrectly. Thus, $0.09x=0.05 \cdot (42-x)$. Now find $x$

Comment: Thank you! I kept trying to put 42 on both sides for some reason. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is asking how many problems you solved correctly, then set

$x$= number of questions solved correctly

given the total number of questions is 42, the number of incorrectly solved questions is $(42-x)$

then, the money will work as: you gained $9x$ cents for correctly solved, and $-5*(42-x)$ cents is the money you lost for incorrect.

provided that "we do not owe each other money", the sum of gain and loss is $0$ cents.

hence a equation of the sum of gain and loss is: $ 0 = 9x -5*(42-x)$. then solve this equation to get $x$.